# Conditional checks not working while processing form in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-2.2

I have a ModelForm (`EditGoalForm`) which I use to edit an instance of a model (`Goal`). Some conditions must be met before saving form data. I used if statements to check these conditions and it still saves, instead of giving an error - like the if statement does nothing.

I have the following:
`models.py`

```py
class Goal(models.Model):
    goal_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    goal_status = models.ForeignKey(GoalStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='goal_status')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='scrumy_goal_user')

class GoalStatus(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

`forms.py`

```py
class EditGoalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    goal_status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GoalStatus.objects.all(), empty_label="Select Goal Status")

    class Meta:
        model = Goal
        fields = ('goal_status',)
```

`views.py`

```
def move_goal(request, goal_id):
    goal_instance = Goal.objects.get(goal_id=goal_id)

    ERROR_MESSAGE = '''BlahBlahBlah'''

    has_perm_cannot_move_to_done = request.user.has_perm('application.cannot_move_to_done')
    has_perm_can_move_goal_anywhere = request.user.has_perm('application.can_move_goal_anywhere')
    has_perm_can_move_someones_goal_from_verify_to_done = request.user.has_perm('application.can_move_someones_goal_from_verify_to_done')
    has_perm_can_move_anybodys_goal_to_any_column = request.user.has_perm('application.can_move_anybodys_goal_to_any_column')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditGoalForm(request.POST, instance=goal_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            if (has_perm_cannot_move_to_done and form.cleaned_data['goal_status'] != 'Done Goal'):
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Goal Update Successful')
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, ERROR_MESSAGE)
    else:
        form = EditGoalForm(instance=goal_instance)
    return render(request, 'move_goal.html', {'form': form})
```

After `if form.is_valid`, I checked if the authenticated user has the permission and if the `goal_status` field was not set to `Done Goal`. If both are True, then save. However, if I set the `goal_status` field to `Done Goal`, it still saves instead of displaying an error message. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share your GoalStatus model as well

Comment: What kind of debugging have you attempted? Did you try to `print` some of the variables? Have you tried to use a step-by-step debugger?

Comment: @cagrias I have updated the question with the GoalStatus model

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, I have printed some variables. I, however, haven't tried a step-by-step debugger

Comment: @Caspian And what was your output? If `form.cleaned_data['goal_status']` is not `'Done Goal'` there is no way that the `if` block was executed

Comment: @DeepSpace `print(form.cleaned_data['goal_status'] != 'Done Goal')` prints True for all instances of GoalStatus -even `Done Goal`

Comment: @Caspian Check for trailing/leading spaces/new lines. Try `form.cleaned_data['goal_status'].strip() != 'Done Goal'`

Comment: @DeepSpace 'GoalStatus' object has no attribute 'strip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.cleaned_data['goal_status']` is an instance of `GoalStatus`. It can never be equal to the string `'Goal Done'` unless you either:

- Implement `__eq__` (and/or) `__ne__`:

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return self.status_name == other
  ```
- Just compare what you really want to compare:

  ```
  form.cleaned_data['goal_status'].status_name != 'Done Goal'
  ```